# Can't move or close Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Although I've migrated off of Eclipse and onto Android Studio for some time now, this is the first time I've used the emulator.  I usually just test on my phone.

I'm having trouble with the emulator on Android Studio.  I'm running on my Microsoft Surface Pro 3 using a large second monitor.  When I start the emulator it appears on the Surface screen stuck to the top as in this screen shot . . .

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39662979/AndriodEmulator.png

The little "x" to kill the emulator is apparently stuck above the top of the screen and the emulator can't be moved.  All I can do is kill it with task manager.  What can I do?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with windows 7 so, am not certain this will help you, but here is what I have to do:

- Hover over the emulator icon on the task bar until it pops up the little preview window.
- Right click on the preview window
- Select 'Move'
- Now you can use the arrow keys on the keyboard to move the window down some so that it's bar is accessible with the mouse so that you can move it to wherever you want it.

Comment: Another way to get that menu is by holding Shift+right clicking the application icon in the taskbar.